# How to link lua-modules to Wireshark-lua-engine?

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

How do I link a module (make it available) to the lua-engine of Wireshark?

Story behind:

I am currently developing a dissector plugin for Wireshark. I wanted to debug my plugin, while beeing executed by Wireshark. I used the mobdebug remote-debugger from https://github.com/pkulchenko/MobDebug which depends on the Luasocket extension. I installed both over luarocks.

I started the debugger-server and I connected in the lua-script (dissector-plugin) to it. But already while loading all scripts at the startup of Wireshark, it fails, telling me that luasocket wasn't found.

Is it a problem that I installed Wireshark over apt-get and didn't compile it from source?

Any ideas on that?

Greetings Theo

Comment: I found my problem. How I mentioned, I used luarocks to install both. But luarocks brought and used the newest version of lua (5.3) as the compiler for mobdebug and luasocket. Here was the problem, my Wireshark version is using lua 5.2 and the standard paths for the libaries had been differnt. Explains the error prompt. So the solution was to compile and install luarocks from source with lua 5.2 and checking the standard library paths. After that no errors.